# OpenCL library missing

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, opencl

When I install NVidia drivers that are listed under "extra drivers" for get-app, I used to get OpenCL drivers, too.  I am using a precompiled App that is trying to dynamically link to the OpenCL library/driver. The error message says

> libOpenCL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

NVidia used to include a proprietary library with their proprietary drivers (called something like nvlibOpenCl.so) which worked, too. Now I do NOT get either one.

I suspect I could install the Developer package, but I'm not a developer and don't need anything except a run-time add-on. Apparently the CUDA 9.0 run-time is already automatically included, but not OpenCL.

I have a **GTX_750_Ti** and a **GTX_960** in this 16.04_LTS system.

The driver is currently NVidia-384

Answer (score 0):

Install the following library:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-libopencl1-340 ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

Comment: The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ocl-icd-opencl-dev : Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1 (= 2.2.8-1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libpoclu-dev but it is not installable

Comment: try to install `sudo apt install ocl-icd-libopencl1` and `sudo apt install ocl-icd-dev` . Please post the whole error message if there is one in your post.

Comment: **ocl-icd-libopencl1 is already the newest version (2.2.8-1).**

Aha, libOpenCL.so is not in the **PATH**.  Shouldn't it be?  ... or somewhere else in the environment so that the program can find?  How do I fix that?